# IBM Cognos adding a total row

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi

I have a list where i have the following attributes: RANK, CLIENT_NAME and AMOUNT. here is an example of the table

```
RANK  CLIENT_NAME  AMOUNT
1     14           10
2     22           305
3     13           56
total              371
```

The problem im having is the following; i'd like to ad a attribute called Total that just shows the total amount. This doens't mean the total amount per client cause i already have that under amount i just want to put a row next to amount that shows the total amount for all clients. so in the example above that would look a little like this:

```
RANK  CLIENT_NAME  AMOUNT  Total_AMOUNT
1     14           10      371
2     22           305     371
3     13           56      371
total              371     371
```

but for some reason i can't figure out how to do this. TOTAL(AMOUNT) doesn't work cause this will filter per client and only show me the total amount per client and not the overall total.

does anyone know how to do this. It would mean so much if someone could help me with this!

Comment: Modify the expression to be `total(amount **for report**)

Comment: thanks this helped me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

afther the comment Andrew has posted I got an idea and made a querycalculated field. filterd on clients (within the parameters) and afther that in a Simple case construction I added the "total(amount for report)" statement that andrew gave me :) thanks man!